# QGIS Select a dimension and change it later

Tags: qgis

Is it possible to change a dimension after initial setting the value?

First of all, how to set a dimension needed by a layer when adding it via browser:
[image]

The Select Dimension dialog does not pop up when doing so. (or maybe I'm doing something wrong?)

Secondly, when adding it via Data Source Manager, the dialog pops up:
[image]

But how to change this value later? adding the Layer again with a different value?

Comment: Sorry, your question in unclear. You should add more information to be able to give an answer